# \renewcommand not working for IEEE subsection

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I wanted to number sections with alphabets and subsections with roman numbers

I have added these two lines above `\begin{document}`:

```
\renewcommand \thesection {\Alph{section}} 
\renewcommand \thesubsection {\thesection.\Roman{subsection}}
```

It changes the section numbering to A, B, C, ... from the default I, II, III, ..., but the subsection numbering is still the default A, B, C, ...

[image]

I have also tried this and it did not work either.

```
\renewcommand \thesubsection {\Roman{subsection}}
```

I have also tried to change the numbering of paragraphs, but there was no change from the default.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Since your section header is centered I suppose that you have more commands. Please, show the minimal code to reproduce the problem. Here those two commands worked well.

Comment: @Sigur no; there are no additional commands; the document class used is `IEEtran` which produces those headings by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using the `IEEEtran` document class with no special options, you need to redefine the family of commands with a `dis` suffix, since in that case the class has

```
\else% not compsoc
  \def\thesectiondis{\thesection.}                   % I.
  \def\thesubsectiondis{\Alph{subsection}.}          % B.
  \def\thesubsubsectiondis{\arabic{subsubsection})}  % 3)
  \def\theparagraphdis{\alph{paragraph})}            % d)
\fi
```

So for subsections, subsubsections and paragraphs you need a redefinition of `\thesubsectiondis`, `\thesubsubsectiondis` and `\theparagraphdis`, respectively.

A complete example (adjust the redefinitions to suit your needs):

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}} 
\renewcommand\thesubsectiondis{\thesection.\Roman{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsectiondis{\thesubsectiondis.\alph{subsubsection}}
\renewcommand\theparagraphdis{\arabic{paragraph}.}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection}
\paragraph{Test paragraph}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for delayed comment. I have made a related to your post question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/708169/adjust-ieee-appendix-numbering-and-ensure-accurate-cross-referencing). Can you please take a look and provide some help?

Answer (score 2):

You should provide a MWE to figure out what your problem is. Any way, you can use the following two commands in the preamble as the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Roman{subsection}}
\begin{document}
\section{My first section}
Text of the first section  goes here.
\subsection{My first subsection}
Text of the  first subsection goes here
\subsection{My second subsection}
Text of the  second subsection goes here
\section{My second section}
Text of the second section  goes here
\subsection{My first subsection}
Text of the  first subsection goes here
\subsection{And finally my second subsection}
Finally, text of the second subsection goes here
\end{document}
```

This should work with you.

The output of the above code is as desired:

[image]

Comment: No, this won't work since the document class used by the OP is `IEEEtran` with no options which uses a different set of commands for the representations of the counters.