# Adjust IEEE Appendix Numbering and Ensure Accurate Cross-Referencing

Tags: cross-referencing, appendices, ieeetran

I am currently working on the following example, but the cross-referencing is not being displayed correctly. Instead of the expected `Appendix A.1` and `Appendix A.2`, it shows `Appendix A` and `Appendix B`. Could someone please suggest a solution to rectify this issue?

```
\documentclass[lettersize,journal]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\title{How to Use the IEEEtran \LaTeX \ Templates}
\author{IEEE Publication Technology Department}

\maketitle


\section{Introduction}



Appendix \ref{appendix:proofXX}


Appendix \ref{appendix:proofYY}

\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Appendices}
\appendix

\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}} 
\renewcommand\thesubsectiondis{\thesection.\Roman{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsectiondis{\thesubsectiondis.\alph{subsubsection}}
\renewcommand\theparagraphdis{\arabic{paragraph}.}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{A\arabic{equation}}
% \renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}} % Redefine equation numbering

% \numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
% \numberwithin{equation}{section}
\setcounter{equation}{0}

\newtheorem{thma}{Theorem}[subsection]
\newtheorem{lema}{Lemma}[subsection]
\newtheorem{defina}{Definition}[subsection]
\newtheorem{rmrka}{Remark}[subsection]
\newtheorem{assuma}{Assumption}[subsection]

\subsection{Proof of Proposition XX}\label{appendix:proofXX}

\subsection{Proof of Proposition YY}\label{appendix:proofYY}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think `IEEEtran` provides a custom macro `\appendices`, so the appendix sections would look different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\thesubsectiondis` controls how the counter is displayed with `\subsection`, but `\thesubsection` still controls the display when referenced. So just redefine `\thesubsection` to match.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\title{How to Use the IEEEtran \LaTeX \ Templates}
\author{IEEE Publication Technology Department}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Appendix \ref{appendix:proofXX}

Appendix \ref{appendix:proofYY}

\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Appendices}
\appendix

\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\Roman{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsectiondis{\thesection.\Roman{subsection}}

\subsection{Proof of Proposition XX}\label{appendix:proofXX}

\subsection{Proof of Proposition YY}\label{appendix:proofYY}

\end{document}
```

[image: ieee]